# Openshift - Pod associated with a service shows "x" against Receiving Traffic Option

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, redhat, kubernetes-helm

I noticed that in the Pod associated with a service shows "x" against Receiving Traffic Option.

The tooltip text for the "x" image says "The pod has no endpoints and is not accepting traffic".

And yes when i hit the service endpoint i get a HTTP 502 back.

Could you please tell whats wrong with the POD.

Here is my service description:

```
Namespace:         mynamespace
Labels:            app=myapp
Selector:          app.kubernetes.io/instance=myapp-instance
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                xx.xx.xxx.xxx
Port:              80-http  80/TCP
TargetPort:        http/TCP
Endpoints:
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

and in my pod i see the label:
 `app.kubernetes.io/instance=myapp-instance`

Comment: what is the output of kubectl describe svc servicename ? are you hitting the service IP or Pod IP?

Comment: The EndPoints: property is blank

Comment: can you add pod and service yaml

Comment: pods are up and running/

Comment: Yes the pod is up and running though.

Comment: Can you provide pod/deployment and service yaml file ?

Answer (score 0):

Describing the service should show endpoints as empty in this case which explains the error.

```
kubectl describe svc servicename
```

You should check that the `spec.selector` field of your Service actually selects for `metadata.labels` values on your Pods. A common mistake is to have a typo or other error, such as the Service selecting for `app=hostnames`, but the Deployment specifying `run=hostnames`.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#does-the-service-have-any-endpoints

Comment: In my service this is all i have 
```
Name:              my-service
Namespace:         my-namespace
Labels:            app=my-service
Selector:          app.kubernetes.io/instance=my-pod-v1
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                xx.xx.xxx.xxx
Port:              80-http  80/TCP
TargetPort:        http/TCP
Endpoints:
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>```

Comment: and in my pod i see the app.kubernetes.io/instance=my-pod-v1 label

Comment: Please update your question with this information, paste code in proper format ?